# message is not defined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Please help, I'm a beginner in discord.js. Here is my index.js:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const { prefix, token } = require("./config.json");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./commands");

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(message.content);
});

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

try {
    command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply("there was an error trying to execute that command!");
}

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.login(token);
```

Error Message here:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
             ^

    ReferenceError: message is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\HxH\index.js:18:14)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Thanks for seeing it.

Comment: It's not defined because you're outside of the `client.on('message', message => ...` part. Did you accidentally close it after `console.log(message.content);`?

Comment: The closing `});` after `console.log(message.content);` should be moved right before `client.login(token)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because all message code is outside your

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    
});
```

Statment.
message is a Variable that gets made in the client.on message statment so It all has to be in there.

Answer (score 0):

This error appered because you close the '})' before the other code

you should remove the }) or put the code in before the }) closes